# Unable to get Youtube iframe to work on iOS11 & iOS10

Tags: swift, iframe, youtube, wkwebview

I'm currently trying to load a youtube video inline on iOS10 & 11. But the video doesn't seem to load at all, I've tested this on iOS12 & 13 and it works the video loads into the iframe and I can play the video. But on iOS10 & 11 I'm just getting a black screen, with no loaded video on it.

This is currently how I'm loading the iframe into my WKWebView.

```
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    self.webView?.apply(height: 500, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    self.webView?.loadHTMLString(#"<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\#(id)?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&vq=highres&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"#, baseURL: nil)
```

I've tried to remove the url parameters too to see if this makes a difference and load in the following url.

```
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    self.webView?.apply(height: 500, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    self.webView?.loadHTMLString(#"<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\#(id)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"#, baseURL: nil)
```

But I'm still getting the same results...Is it possible to load a iframe into a WKWebView on iOS10 & 11? Or is this a limitation?